# Python cast to datetime in single line loop

Tags: python, datetime

Can I cast this string to a datetime object whilst still keeping it in a single line loop?

```
dt=[r['datetimestring'] for r in data]
```

Comment: can you post what is in data? e.g. via `print(data)`?

Comment: `Can I cast this string to a datetime object ` -> why don't you try and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? This is not a limit of list comprehension:

```
from datetime import datetime

format = '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p' #it is possible you have to alter it to your own format

dt=[datetime.strptime(r['datetimestring'],format) for r in data]
```

where format is the specification of your datetime format.

List comprehension is simply:

```
[ <expression> for <variables> in <iterable> ]
```

as long as `<expression>` somehow generates a value, it is fine.